# Possible to rewrite this so that I don't have to assign this to a variable when using promises

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript2.0

We have run into some issues with TypeScript and this. Is it possible to rewrite the callbacks below without assigning this to that?

Within my namespace, in the same file as this component, I have an enum:

```
enum ToggleStates {
  State1 = 1,
  State2,
  State3
}
```

Then in a function in the same component:

```
  let that = this;

  defer.then(function(response) {
      if (response.success !== null) { // if there is a success handler
        that.$rootScope.$broadcast("w-signed", this.toggleStates, this.currentSigned);
      }else {
        that.$rootScope.addAlert("danger", error);
      }
  }).catch(function(response) {
      that.$rootScope.addAlert("danger", error);
  }).finally(function() {
      that.$rootScope.addAlert("danger", error);
  });
```

For a similar problem, we  used lambdas to get around the issue. I tried the following:

```
  defer.then = (response) => {
      if (response.success !== null) { // if there is a success handler
        this.$rootScope.$broadcast("w-signed", this.toggleStates, this.currentSigned);
      }else {
        this.$rootScope.addAlert("danger", error);
      }
  }

  defer.catch = (response) => {
       this.$rootScope.addAlert("danger", error);
  }

  defer.finally = () => {
    this.$rootScope.addAlert("danger", error);
  }
```

But then I get the following error:

```
wp-leftnavcomponent.ts(208,65): error TS2339: Property 'toggleStates' does not exist on type 'WpListComponentController'.
```

Comment: How is toggleStates thing related to the question? There's no mention where toggleStates comes from.

Comment: Good point. Just added more info

Comment: There's no WpListComponentController in the code above. And it misses toggleStates property in class definition. That's what the error says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting `then`/`catch`/`finally` with the lambdas instead of passing them in. The only bit you need to replace in your original example is `function () { }` with `() => {}`.

```
defer.then((response) => {
    if (response.success !== null) { // if there is a success handler
        this.$rootScope.$broadcast("w-signed", this.toggleStates, this.currentSigned);
    }
    else {
        this.$rootScope.addAlert("danger", error);
    }
})
.catch((response) => {
    this.$rootScope.addAlert("danger", error);
})
.finally(() => {
    this.$rootScope.addAlert("danger", error);
});
```

Comment: The enum is declared as a local variable. It's not attached to the WpListComponentController object.